# Smooth continuous character movement issue in react game - timing and animation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I attempted to create a game character movement in a React, but I got a problem when I try to move the character continuously (Holding down the key movements without releasing it). Here's my logic:

1. User presses the arrow keys to move the character.
2. If the character still on animation abort it.
3. Set the character to on animation.
4. Animate the character using translation to slide to another div (using css transition).
5. Update the characterPosition state to the destination div using `setTimeout()` (basically I tried to make the characterPosition state changes after the css animation done).
6. Set the character to idle.

[My Layout Preview Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNbvR.png)

If I hold down my arrow key without releasing it, my character seems to be jumping sometimes. But it's doing just fine if I give a delay on pressing my arrow keys on my keyboard. I'm assuming that it's got something to do with the timing of React state and setTimeout() function.

#### Here's the code

```
const [isCharacterMoving, setIsCharacterMoving] = useState(false);
const [characterPosition, setCharacterPosition] = useState({ rowCell: 5, colCell: 41 });

const moveDisplayCharacter = (event: KeyboardEvent) => {
  // ABORTING MOVEMENT IF THE CHARACTER STILL ON ANIMATION
  if (isCharacterMoving) return;
  // ...
  } else if (key === "ArrowRight" && ...)
    moveAnimation("Right");
  }
  //...
}

const moveAnimation = (heading: string) => {
 // ...
 } else if (heading == "Right") {
    translationObject.current = { dx: `-${cellWidth.current}px`, dy: `0px` };
 }
 // ...

 setIsCharacterMoving(true);
 setTimeout(() => {
     // CHANGE THE STATE TO NOT MOVING
     ...
     moveRefCharacter(heading);
     setIsCharacterMoving(false);
     ...
 }, 300);

const moveRefCharacter = (heading: string) => {
 // CHANGING THE STATE OF THE CHARACTER POSITION
  setCharacterPosition(...);
 // ...
}
```

#### This is how I rendered my character

For each square that hold as a character container it's actually a div

[Character Container Div Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCYO0.png)

```
<div id=`{cell-row${uniqe-id}}` className={`...`}>
  // CONDITION IF THE CURRENT "cell-row" IS EQUAL TO 'characterPosition' RENDER IT
  // if(...){
  <Image
     style={{
          //...
          transition: 'transform 0.3s ease-in-out',
          transform: isCharacterMoving ? `translate(${translation.current.dx}, ${translation.current.dy})`: 'none',
     }}
  />
</div>
```

I've try to abort the character movements if the character is still on animations, but it doesn't work.

This is the full code : https://github.com/daffavcd/MyLittlePrison/blob/f8c5e5053c6c277fa9feecf2152d791d28ce76ef/src/app/components/game.tsx

You can try to move the character by holding down the 'LeftArrow' or 'RightArrow' keyboard keys without releasing it here :
https://mylittleprison.netlify.app/

Do you have any idea what's going on? Really appreciate it for your time here. Thank you so much!

Character moves smoothly when I hold down the character movement keys without releasing it.